# Passing values back from threads to the main thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create a main thread which adds to the sum the value of the other(secondary) threads after they finish executing. I can't manage to pass the secondary threads value to the main one.

```
public class RandomThread implements Runnable {

   private int rnd;

    public int getRnd() {
        return rnd;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    }


    public RandomThread(int min, int max) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNumber = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        this.rnd = randomNumber;
        System.out.println(rnd);

    }

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t4 = new Thread(new RandomThread(1, 10));
        try {
            t4.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t4.start();


        Thread t5 = new Thread(new RandomThread(1, 10));
        try {
            t5.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t5.start();

        Thread t6 = new Thread(new RandomThread(1, 10));
        try {
            t6.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t6.start();

        Thread t7 = new Thread(new RandomThread(1, 10));
        try {
            t7.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t7.start();

        Thread t8 = new Thread(new RandomThread(1, 10));

        try {
            t8.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t8.start();
    }

}
```

I need another thread which will be something like this. "New Thread = t4 value + t5 value + t6 value + t7 value + t8 value".

Comment: Try `ThreadPoolExecutor`s and `Future`s.

Comment: Your threads don't actually do anything when they run. You do all the operations in their constructor, which is invoked *in the main thread*. Also, `Thread.sleep` is a *static* method. Running `t8.sleep()` is not going to make `t8` sleep. It's going to make the *current* thread (the main thread) sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a really verbose example of what this might look like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

class RandomThread implements Runnable {
  private final Random rand;
  private final int min;
  private final int max;
  private int rnd;

  public int getRnd() {
    return rnd;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    final String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " started. Sleeping for 5000ms to simulate work being done...");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final int randomNumber = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    this.rnd = randomNumber;
    System.out.println("Generated [" + rnd + "] in thread " + threadName);
  }


  public RandomThread(int min, int max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    rand = new Random();
  }
}

class TestClass {

  private static final int NUM_THREADS = 10;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    final List<RandomThread> runnables = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
      runnables.add(new RandomThread(1, 10));
    }
    System.out.println("Runnables created.");

    final List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final RandomThread runnable : runnables) {
      threads.add(new Thread(runnable));
    }
    System.out.println("Threads created.");

    for (final Thread thread : threads) {
      thread.start();
    }
    System.out.println("Threads started.");

    for (final Thread thread : threads) {
      try {
        thread.join();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Threads stopped (complete).");

    int total = 0;
    for (final RandomThread runnable : runnables) {
      total += runnable.getRnd();
    }
    System.out.println("Total: " + total);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need another thread which will be something like this. "New Thread = t4 value + t5 value + t6 value + t7 value + t8 value".

As mentioned by others, if you call `join()` on your threads this will synchronize memory with the thread and you can call `getRnd()` to get the random number.

I would instead use the great [`ExecutorService` and associated classes](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html) and submit `Callable<Integer>` instead of `Runnable` instances.  `Callable` actually returns a value that you can then retrieve.

You could do something like the following:

```
public class RandomCallable implements Callable<Integer> {
    ...
    public Integer call() {
       Random rand = new Random();
       int randomNumber = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
       return randomNumber;
    }
} 
...

// create a thread pool
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
List<Future<Integer>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
// submit a callable (or many) and record the future returned
futures.add(threadPool.submit(new RandomCallable(1, 10)));
// once you have submitted all of your jobs, shutdown the pool
threadPool.shutdown();
// now wait for and add up the results
int total = 0;
for (Future<Integer> future : futures) {
   total += future.get();
}
```

Lastly, as mentioned by @Vincente, you should not be doing the random operations in the *constructor* of `RandomThread` because those will be calculated by the main thread since it calls the constructors.  Also, your class is not a thread, it should be either `RandomRunnable` or `RandomCallable`.

Comment: Ty for the info, i actually thought there was an easier way which would not involve lists, atomic integers and so on.

Comment: What you have is close @Paul but once you start using the `ExecutorService` classes, they will see that they are pretty easy as well and you don't have to write your own code to do things.  You are going to have to store a list of your threads and then loop through them to join them all so the code is close to being the same.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you place all the logic to calculate a random number inside the constructor of the RandomThread class, you are not doing a multithread sum, but only a sequential sum. You should put all that logic inside the "run()" method. Then, you have to make calls to "join()" on each of the threads to make sure the program won't exit before each thread has calculated its number, so that the main thread can retrieve this number through "getRnd()".

Anyway, you should look at the ExecutorService element, which provides an easy way to start threads and wait for their results.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a couple of mistakes.

-you should start the thread first:

-then invoke .join, not sleep

```
public class TestClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread t4 = new Thread(new RandomThread(1, 10));
    t4.start();
    try {
        t4.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    .....
}
```

Comment: Yes, i am aware of that. I was using sleep to delay the execution. Thank you for the other observation. I am still new to threads and i am making newbie mistakes.

Comment: @Gray The original class provided for that, so I thought he could use getRnd(), but he'd need a cast back to RandomThread for that.